# c++ template refactor/generalisation

Tags: c++, c++11

Can this code be generalized so I can have a variable amount of types/arguments?

(I really prefer to keep the functions out of the struct to keep the code more clean.)

```
unsigned int const maxID = 2 ^ 8;
typedef unsigned int ID;

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3, typename T4, typename T5, typename T6>
struct SOA {
    T1 a1[maxID];
    T2 a2[maxID];
    T3 a3[maxID];
    T4 a4[maxID];
    T5 a5[maxID];
    T6 a6[maxID];
    ID currentMaxID = 0;
};

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3, typename T4, typename T5, typename T6>
ID AddEntity(SOA<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6>& soa, T1 a1, T2 a2, T3 a3, T4 a4, T5 a5, T6 a6) {
    soa.a1[soa.currentMaxID] = a1;
    soa.a2[soa.currentMaxID] = a2;
    soa.a3[soa.currentMaxID] = a3;
    soa.a4[soa.currentMaxID] = a4;
    soa.a5[soa.currentMaxID] = a5;
    soa.a6[soa.currentMaxID] = a6;
    return soa.currentMaxID++;
}

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3, typename T4, typename T5, typename T6>
ID RemoveEntity(SOA<T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6>& soa, ID entityID) {
    soa.currentMaxID--;
    soa.a1[entityID] = soa.a1[soa.currentMaxID];
    soa.a2[entityID] = soa.a2[soa.currentMaxID];
    soa.a3[entityID] = soa.a3[soa.currentMaxID];
    soa.a4[entityID] = soa.a4[soa.currentMaxID];
    soa.a5[entityID] = soa.a5[soa.currentMaxID];
    soa.a6[entityID] = soa.a6[soa.currentMaxID];
}
```

Comment: You can store it as an array of tuples.

Comment: Can you please show me how to do that?

Comment: Something like `template <typename... T> struct SOA { std::tuple<T...> a[maxID]; };`

Comment: The types have to be linear in memory. Like T1...T1, T2...T2, etc.
Will std::tuple<T...> a[maxID]; not arrange them like T1, T2, T3 ... T1, T2, T3?

Comment: How about a `std::tuple<std::array<T, MaxId>...>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

```
using ID = unsigned int;;
ID const maxID = 1<<8;

template <typename... Ts>
struct SOA {
  std::tuple< std::array< Ts, maxID >... > a;
  ID currentMaxID = 0;
};
```

Some boilerplate you don't need in C++14: (`std::decay_t` and `std::integral_sequence<unsigned` replace them).

```
template<unsigned...>struct indexes{using type=indexes;};
template<unsigned Max, unsigned...Is>struct make_indexes:make_indexes<Max-1,Max-1,Is...>{};
template<unsigned...Is>struct make_indexes<0,Is...>:indexes<Is...>{};
template<unsigned Max>using make_indexes_t=typename make_indexes<Max>::type;
template<class T>using decay_t=typename std::decay<T>::type;
```

Actual work.  First, helper `details`:

```
namespace details {
  template <typename... Ts, unsigned... Is>
  ID AddEntity(indexes<Is...>, SOA<Ts...>& soa, decay_t<Ts> const&... ts) {
    int unused[] = { ( (std::get<Is>(soa.a)[soa.currentMaxID] = ts ), void(), 0 )..., 0 };
    (void)(unused); // just blocks warnings
    return soa.currentMaxID++;
  }
  template <typename... Ts, unsigned... Is>
  void RemoveEntity(indexes<Is...>, SOA<Ts...>& soa, ID entityID) {
    --soa.currentMaxID;
    int unused[] = {
      ( (std::get<Is>(soa.a)[entityId] = std::get<Is>(soa.a)[soa.currentMaxID] ),
      void(), 0 )..., 0
    };
    (void)(unused); // just blocks warnings
  }
}
```

which uses the array-to-do-many-things-trick.  Then:

```
template <typename... Ts>
ID AddEntity(SOA<Ts...>& soa, decay_t<Ts> const&... ts) {
  return details::AddEntity( make_indexes_t< sizeof...(Ts) >{}, soa, ts... );
}

template <typename...Ts>
void RemoveEntity(SOA<Ts...>& soa, ID entityID) {
  details::RemoveEntity( make_indexes_t< sizeof...(Ts) >{}, soa, entityID );
}
```

[or something like that (live example)](http://ideone.com/KoCpB1).

Note that I support the empty collection of `Ts...`.

Comment: How can I also support the empty collection of Ts... ?
When I try to compile your code I get errors in the details namespace at Is... and Ts...

Comment: Sorry but I can't make your code compile. I get errors about Ts and Is in the details namespace.

Comment: @ChristianD. ok, it now compiles.

Comment: This line does not compile: int unused[] = { ( std::get<Is>(soa)[soa.currentMaxID] = ts ), void(), 0 )..., 0 };

Comment: And also this line:
int unused[] = {
      ( std::get<Is>(soa)[soa.entityId] = std::get<Is>(soa)[soa.currentMaxID] ),
      void(), 0 )..., 0
    };

Comment: @ChristianD. I would guess that your compiler is not C++11 compliant.  Can you mention your compiler in your original post?  Note that I have made further changes to my code to fix typos -- `soa.a` instead of `soa` for example -- including links to live compiling code at ideone.  I'm off to dinner, good luck.

Comment: @christiand. The array trick is to expand the parameter packs one by one and run them in order.  Note that I use `operator,` in there as well.  The indexes trick makes `indexes<0,1,2,3,...,max-1>` to invoke `get` correctly via `make_indexes_t<max>{}`